# Weasyprint cant load images when rendering html string

Tags: python, html, django, templates, weasyprint

I am working on weasyprint library with python, scenario is i wrote a simple function which first renders html template  to html_string with dynamic data and a logo then i am converting that html_string to pdf but the issue is when i am converting the html_string to pdf it doesn't show the image(logo), i went through different solution in which they solved the issue through request.build_absolute_uri() but i don't have request parameter because my function is not a django view, can anyone guide me how can i render the html_template with logo

```
def generatepdf(data):
    html = render_to_string('template.html', {"test": data})
    filename = data['version'] + ".pdf"
    try:
        # pdfkit.from_string(html.content.decode('utf-8'), filename, options=options)
        HTML(string=html).write_pdf(filename)
        return filename
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.__str__())
        return False
```

Comment: if solution can be `build_absolute_uri` then maybe manually create absolute links in your html. OR absolute uri starting at `file://`

Comment: BTW: how do you run this function? If you run it in view then you could define it as `def generatepdf(data, request):` and run with `request`

Comment: BTW: it seems you don't have to run `request.build_absolute_uri()` but you can manually add this url `HTML(string=html_string, base_url="your_absolute_uri")`. You have to only know what value to use as absolute path.

Comment: can you guide me what would be my absolute path my directory is as follows
project/static/logo/file
static directory is also registered

Comment: normal absolute path on disk starts with `C:/` on Windows or with `/` on `Windows/Linux/Mac` - in HTML  it may need prefix `file://` - like `file:///home/user/documents/project/static/logo/file` on Linux. When it has to be absolute path to element on page then it could be `http://your_domain.com/static/logo/file`. But I don't know how it works in PDF.

Comment: I tested it on own HTML file from https://blog.furas.pl/ which uses absolute pathes starting at `/` - ie `<img src="/images/image.jpg">` and it shows images after I use `HTML(html, base_url="https://blog.furas.pl/")` (it doesn't show images without `base_url=`). The only problem is I use lazy loading for images so I have `<img data-src=...` instead of `<img src=...` and normally JavaScript changes it when I scroll page but `weasyprint` can't run JavaScript and it doesn't change `data-src` to `src` and I had to do `html = html.replace('data-src=', 'src=')`

Comment: How can i use lazy loading in my scenario and where i have to change that data-src to src

Comment: you don't need lazy loading. I only mentioned it because if you aleady have something like `data-scr=` or you use JavaScript to add images then you have to remove it because `weasyprint` can't run JavaScript and it changes urls in `scr=` but not in `data-src=`. At this moment you have to only use correct value in `base_url=` - if you run code on server `http://your_domian.com` then you may need `base_url="http://your_domian.com/"`. If you run it on local server then you may need `base_url="http://localhost/"`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `base_url` as mentioned in the comments.
I personally have my image in the same folder as my python file. Just add the absolute path to the folder as the base_url argument.

In the python file:

```py
html = HTML(string=html_string, base_url="/home/whatever/pdf_generator")
```

And in the html_string (absolute path to the image: */home/whatever/pdf_generator/my_image.png*):

```
<img src="my_image.png" />
```